# How to mutate a new column with yes or no value if at least one column from col7 to col10 is equal to 4 in r using dplyr?

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have a data as follows:

```
 col1 <- c(0.1,0.2,0.0,0.5,0.6)
 col2 <- c(2,2,4,5,6)
 col3 <- c(1,4,3,4,5) 
 col4 <- c(2,3,4,4,6)
 col5 <- c(5,3,3,2,1)
 data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)

   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
 1  0.1    2    1    2    5
 2  0.2    2    4    3    3
 3  0.0    4    3    4    3
 4  0.5    5    4    4    2
 5  0.6    6    5    6    1
```

I would like to add a new column with "yes" value where in each row at least one column from col2 to column 5 is equal to 4 and "no" when the data does not meet the criteria.

So the output would look like as:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
 1  0.1    2    1    2    5  no
 2  0.2    2    4    3    3  yes
 3  0.0    4    3    4    3  yes
 4  0.5    5    4    4    2  yes
 5  0.6    6    5    6    1  no
```

here is my command:

```
new.df <- df %>% mutate(df, col6 = funs(ifelse(abs(vars(c(2:5) == 4),"yes", "no")
```

But I can not get the required output. do you have any idea how can I use dplyr, mutate and if else function to get the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can sum when cell ==4 using `rowSums`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(col6 = ifelse(rowSums(.[,c(2:5)]==4)>0, 'yes', 'no'))

col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
1  0.1    2    1    2    5   no
2  0.2    2    4    3    3  yes
3  0.0    4    3    4    3  yes
4  0.5    5    4    4    2  yes
5  0.6    6    5    6    1   no
```

Using @thelatemail suggestion, we can rewrite `ifelse` as below:

```
df %>% mutate(col6 = ifelse(Reduce(`|`, lapply(.[,c(2:5)], `==`, 4)), 'yes', 'no'))
```

Comment: And a functional aternative to the `rowSums` part would be `Reduce(\`|\`, lapply(dat[-1], \`==\`, 4))` if anyone is that way inclined.

Comment: @thelatemail nice use of `==` as a function, thanks for the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `any`

```
ifelse(apply(df[,-1]==4,1,any),'yes','no')
[1] "no"  "yes" "yes" "yes" "no"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some approaches:

**1) rowSums** Compare all but `col1` to 4, sum the comparisons and for each one that is strictly positive choose `yes` else `no`.

```
library(dplyr)

dd %>% 
  mutate(col6 = if_else(rowSums(select(., -col1) == 4) > 0, "yes", "no"))

giving:

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
1  0.1    2    1    2    5   no
2  0.2    2    4    3    3  yes
3  0.0    4    3    4    3  yes
4  0.5    5    4    4    2  yes
5  0.6    6    5    6    1   no
```

**1a) Reduce** A variation of this using `Reduce` would be:

```
dd %>% 
  mutate(col6 = 
    if_else(Reduce("|", (select(., -col1) == 4) %>% as.data.frame), "yes", "no"))
```

**2) gathr** Convert to long form, summarize and join back to the original data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dd %>%
  mutate(seq = 1:n()) %>%
  left_join(gather(., key, value, -seq, -col1) %>%
    group_by(seq) %>%
    summarize(col6 = if_else(any(value == 4), "yes", "no")) %>%
    ungroup) %>%
  select(-seq)
```

If `col1` has unique values, as it does in the sample data shown in the question, then it could be used in place of `seq` shortening the code to:

```
dd %>%
  left_join(gather(., key, value, -col1) %>%
    group_by(col1) %>%
    summarize(col6 = if_else(any(value == 4), "yes", "no")) %>%
    ungroup)
```